# limiting mdfind on Terminal to files changed in the last x minutes/hours?

Tags: terminal, spotlight

It's relatively simple to use `find` to look for recent files.

`find . -cmin -5` will look for all files changed in the last 5 minutes under the current directory.

But `find` is very much slower than `mdfind`, which is powered by Spotlight's index when you search the whole machine.

What is the simplest way, on the terminal, to ask mdfind to only look for files modified in the last 5 minutes?  Every time I look at the Apple doc I get totally lost as to what you actually type on the command line.

Comment: There is `kMDItemFSContentChangeDate` but this is absolute date/time so you would need to do some date arithmetic first.

Comment: I’d accept an actual answer if it the example in it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the time variable- `$time.now` and subtract the number of seconds- `$time.now(-300)` to get 5 minutes before the current time. Next, you would use the operator `>=` for the comparison. To put it all together-

```
 mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemFSContentChangeDate >= $time.now(-300)'
```

Comment: That works.  Seems a bit tricky to wrap in a bash function but it certainly got me started. I do wish this feature had better docs.